# my component isn't shown with React mapping

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I'm trying to render posts that come from my database, the data is printed as an array in the console.log(post) but the post component doesn't render.

Code:

```
{posts && posts.map((post, key) => {
   {console.log(post)}
   <ConnectPost postDetails={post} key={key} />
})}
```

Data Array example:

```
{
    "post_id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "placed_by": "youtuber",
    "link": "https://www.youtube.com/c/MrBeast6000",
    "game_id": null,
    "game_name": null,
    "requirements": "{\"minimum game size\": 1000}"
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return `ConnectPost` from map function. Simply do `return <ConnectPost postDetails={post} key={key} />`. If you are not returning anything from `map` then `undefined` will return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add return :

```
{posts && posts.map((post, key) => {
   {console.log(post)}
  return <ConnectPost postDetails={post} key={key} />
})}
```